# Como colocar divs responsivas independentemente do tamanho do height?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3, height

Tenho um projeto em Bootstrap com 4 divs em cada linha, lado a lado comportando-se de forma responsiva. Cada uma das divs têm um determinado conteúdo. A largura das imagens será fixa mas a altura não. Se uma das imagens tiver maior `height`, o restante conteúdo das outras divs comporta-se de forma estranha, conforme imagem:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Há alguma forma de alterar isso? No fundo pretendo que, independentemente do tamanho do `height`, as divs fiquem sempre com a mesma distância entre elas ao diminuir o tamanho do ecrã/*browser*. Neste momento, se aumentar a `height` de uma imagem, a de baixo fica com uma distância gigante da de cima.

O meu html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SmartEvents</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A Tuts+ course">
        <!-- Mobile Specific Meta -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento1a.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">Gratuito</div>
                            <div class="events-name">DJ Precatado Tour Smart 2015</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Música</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Meo Arena</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Inscrever-se</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento2.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">20.00€ - 45.00€</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Vinil e K7. Passado e futuro.</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Conferências</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Armazém 77</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Comprar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento3.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">Gratuito</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Como fazer massa italiana em português</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Restaurante Pasta e pinhões</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Inscrever-se</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento4.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">2.500€</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Windows 28 - Como entrar?</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Chalet suiço Bill Gates</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Comprar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento3.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">2.500€</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Windows 28 - Como entrar?</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Chalet suiço Bill Gates</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Comprar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento3.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">Gratuito</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Como fazer massa italiana em português</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Restaurante Pasta e pinhões</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Inscrever-se</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento3.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">Gratuito</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Como fazer massa italiana em português</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Restaurante Pasta e pinhões</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Inscrever-se</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="events-box">
                            <img src="images/evento3.jpg" />
                            <div class="events-cost">Gratuito</div>
                            <div class="events-name">Como fazer massa italiana em português</div>
                            <div class="events-cat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin" aria-hidden="true"></span> Aulas e Workshops</div>
                            <div class="events-place"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></span> Restaurante Pasta e pinhões</div>
                            <div class="events-date"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span> 12 Dez 2015, 21:30</div>
                            <div class="events-action">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Inscrever-se</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
        <div class="main-box-footer">
            <div class="content">
                <p class="main-title blue-title">Eventos por categoria.</p>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Concerto <span class="badge">8</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Gastronomia <span class="badge">12</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Aulas e Workshops <span class="badge">7</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Desporto <span class="badge">15</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Conferências <span class="badge">3</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Cinema <span class="badge">10</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Festival <span class="badge">2</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Negócios <span class="badge">5</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Festas <span class="badge">1</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Artes Performativas <span class="badge">9</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Ciência <span class="badge">6</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
                            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Saúde <span class="badge">4</span></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
        <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

O meu css:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */
 body {
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* TEXTOS*/
 h1 {
    font-size:40px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color: #52b266;
}

.blue-title {
    font-size:35px;
    color:#333c4e;
}

.blue-sub-title, .white-sub-title {
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.blue-sub-title {
    color:#333c4e;
}

.white-sub-title {
    color:#fff;
}

/* TEXTOS*/
 .main-title {
    max-width:1130px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.main-box-header {
    background:#e6f0f3;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.main-box-footer {
    background:#e6f0f3;
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    margin:0px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:left;
}

.content {
    max-width:1130px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.events-box {
    background:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    max-width:300px;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #888888;
    padding:20px;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.events-box img {
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.events-cost {
    color:#00a651;
    background:white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    /* For IE8 and earlier */
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-top:-20px;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:100%;
}

.events-name {
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.events-place {
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:#ACACAC;
}

.events-date {
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:#ACACAC;
}

.events-cat {
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:#666;
}

.events-action {
    max-width:100%;
    text-align:right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.list-categorias {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    padding:30px;
    background:#e6f0f3;
}

.badge {
    background-color:#0d1014;
}

.footer {
    background:#333c4e;
    height:200px;
    padding-top:20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {

    .blue-sub-title {
        font-size:14px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size:20px;
        color:#FFF;
        background-color: #52b266;
    }

    .white-sub-title {
        display:none;
    }

    .events-box {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
    }

    .events-box img {
        max-width:100%;
    }

    .events-cost {
        max-width:100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que isso seja possível você pode utilizar:

**Min-height**: atribui as div's o atributo min-height com o valor da div mais alta. Porem não aconselho usar esse se o conteúdo for gerenciavel.

Ex.:

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid rgb(0, 100, 125);
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 250px;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nun</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nunc nulla, ullamcorper id egestas ut, laoreet nec mauris</div>
```

---

**Atribuir height para o "container"**: caso você atribua valor fixo para o node "pai" ou "container" você pode dizer que as filhas, terão 100% da altura do node "pai".

Ex.:

```css
#box {
  height: 250px;
}
.box-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="box-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nun</div>
  <div class="box-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nunc nulla, ullamcorper id egestas ut, laoreet nec mauris</div>
</div>
```

---

**Flex-box**: Utilizando o *Flexible Box Model* você pode atribuir altura de 100% para os filho utilizando o valor stretch para a propriedade *justify-content*.

Ex.:

```css
#box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: space-around;
}
.box-item {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="box-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nun</div>
  <div class="box-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur eu rhoncus nulla, ut dignissim enim. Integer nunc nulla, ullamcorper id egestas ut, laoreet nec mauris</div>
</div>
```

OBS.: Esse é apenas um exemplo básico de *flex-box*, caso você pretenda usa-lo indico que leia [esse post](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) e [esse](http://tableless.com.br/flexbox-organizando-seu-layout/) do CSS tricks e Tableless respectivamente e utilize os devidos vendor-prefixes (-webkit, -moz, -ms...).
Você pode ver [aqui](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) o suporte atual dessa propriedade pelos navegadores.

---

Há também outras soluções, mas recomendo que utilize alguma dessas.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, você poderia setar um `Max-height` e um `Max-width` na dimensão da imagem, com isso não iria dar problema, ou limitar o usuário e sempre input a imagem em uma tamanho especifico.

Segue abaixo as propriedades CSS `Max`
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dimension.asp

Comment: não há forma de, independentemente do [height] da imagem, a div imediatamente em baixo não descer, mantendo sempre o mesmo espaçamento entre as divs?